# Client/Server Program: Connection Reset

Tags: java, sockets, io

I have written a basic program to demonstrate client server interaction. Connection is getting established but unable to fetch the data from stream. It throws an exception stating the connection reset

### Server

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketServer {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private int port;

    public SocketServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void start() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Starting the socket server at port:" + port);
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

        sendWelcomeMessage(client);
    }

    private void sendWelcomeMessage(Socket client) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new                        OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        writer.write("Hello. You are connected to a Simple Socket Server. What is your   name?");
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
    * Creates a SocketServer object and starts the server.
    *
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Setting a default port number.
        int portNumber = 9990;

        try {
            // initializing the Socket Server
            SocketServer socketServer = new SocketServer(portNumber);
            socketServer.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Client

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class SocketClient {

private String hostname;
private int port;
Socket socketClient;

public SocketClient(String hostname, int port){
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.port = port;
}

public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    System.out.println("Attempting to connect to "+hostname+":"+port);
    socketClient = new Socket(hostname,port);
    System.out.println("Connection Established");
}

public void readResponse() throws IOException{
    String userInput;
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println("Response from server:");
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(userInput);
    }
}

public static void main(String arg[]){
    //Creating a SocketClient object
    SocketClient client = new SocketClient ("localhost",9990);
    try {
        //trying to establish connection to the server
        client.connect();
        //if successful, read response from server
        client.readResponse();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Host unknown. Cannot establish connection");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot establish connection. Server may not be up."+e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

##OUTPUT##

Attempting to connect to localhost:9990
Connection Established
Response from server:
Hello. You are connected to a Simple Socket Server. What is your name?
       java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at SocketClient.readResponse(SocketClient.java:31)
    at SocketClient.main(SocketClient.java:45)
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 3) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 4) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's at least one thing wrong with the current implementation. You utilise `readLine()` to get the data - however `readLine()` does this:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Your program that emits the data does not use a newline character to terminate the "message":

```
writer.write("Hello. You are connected to a Simple Socket Server. What is your name?");
writer.flush();
```

To terminate the message, add a newline:

```
writer.write("Hello. You are connected to a Simple Socket Server. What is your name?");
writer.write("\n");              // shown separately for clarity
writer.flush();
```

Comment: But soon after it prints the data from the input. It still throws an exception. How do i avoid it

Comment: @user2186265: Actually, I'm not convinced my answer is correct - a quick test I wrote showed that `readLine()` returned the data in the stream up until the point the connection was closed.  To really debug this, we need to see the real exceptions that are being generated, as indicated by Andrew.  Answer has been edited to only point out the problem with the newline.

Comment: i fixed it. It was because i was using while loop to fetch input from the server and hence it was iterating for infinite time until the connection stopped. I do not if it was right. But fixed the problem for now. And i thin i still fear that server is closing the TCP connection before the client notification.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually been wrestling with this for a while as well, but I believe I have found a more accurate answer, and thought I should share it. The original example never closes the `BufferedWriter`. So simply add `writer.close()` after `writer.flush()`, like so:

```
writer.write("Hello. You are connected to a Simple Socket Server. What is your name?");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Because it was never closed, the output was never null, so the `while` loop was never failing.

Comment: No. Because it was never closed, `readLine()` never returned null at the peer. That's not the same thing as the output being null. It isn't null. The statement doesn't make sense.